# Restart loop and add values in python?

Tags: python, statistics, probability

The problem:
There are 3 paths where only one leads home.

- The first path gets you lost for 3 days, then you're back to the beginning where you have to pick another path.
- The second path gets you lost for 2 days, then you're back at the beginning and you have to pick another path.
- The last door leads you home in 1 day.

Basically you keep going until you pick the last path. I'm trying to find the average time it takes to get home by simulating 1000 tries.
Here is what I have thus far:

```
 days=0
 for i in range(1000):
     door=["a","b","c"]
     numpy.random.choice(path)
     if numpy.random.choice(path)=="a":
         days=+2
     if numpy.random.choice(path)=="b":
         days=+3       
     if numpy.random.choice(path)=="c":
         days=+1
 print(steps)
```

As is, my code will just print out a value from 1-3 as the days.
I'm having trouble figuring out how to pick one and then accumulate it into the days and then restarting the loop until it picks path C.
I've done research and think a while loop might work but I don't know how to apply that.

Comment: print 'steps'? where is 'steps' defined? Where is `path` defined?

Comment: Cute problem, but why are you using Numpy for this? Just call the `random` module functions directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a while loop that keeps iterating while you are stuck and then when door 'a' is selected it adds the 1 to get home but then the person is no longer stuck so it drops out of the while loop. Then before entering the while loop again, just set `stuck = True` and the process continues always adding to the total number of days, then at the end just take the average.

```
import numpy

days=0
door=["a","b","c"]

N = 1000
for i in range(N):
    stuck = True

    while stuck:
        if numpy.random.choice(door)=="a":
            days += 2

        if numpy.random.choice(door)=="b":
            days += 3

        if numpy.random.choice(door)=="c":
            days += 1
            stuck = False

print('Average number of days taken to get home: ', days / N)
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code you're looking for:

```
import numpy

def runOnce():
    days = 0
    door=["a","b","c"]
    while(True):
        path = numpy.random.choice(door)
        if path=="a":
            days+=2

        if path=="b":
            days+=3

        if path=="c":
            days+=1
            return days
total = 0
for i in range(1000):
    total += runOnce()

print(total / 1000.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code must solve your problem:

```
import random

doors = ['a', 'b', 'c']
total_days = 0
runs = 1000
for i in range(runs):
    days = 0
    choice = None

    while choice != 'c':
        choice = random.choice(doors)
        if choice == 'a': 
            days += 2
        if choice == 'b':
            days += 3
        if choice == 'c':
            days += 1
    total_days += days
avg_days = total_days / runs
print(avg_days)
```

Comment: Carefull with integer division! If you calculate total_days = 999 you'll get avg_days = 0. Just change `total_days = 0` to `total_days = 0.0`

Comment: @Stein What integer division? That code will only perform integer division if you run it on Python 2. And in this day and age, one should assume the OP is using Python 3 unless they state otherwise, or it's obvious from their code. ;)

Comment: Fair enough. Sadly lots of programs still require python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure on your rules, but this is my attempt

```
import numpy as np

def choose_path():
    p =np.random.randint(3)
    #print("Path = {}".format(p))
    return p


N = 100000

days=0.0
for i in range(N):
    #make sure you don't take the wrong path twice
    taken = [False, False, False]

    path = choose_path()
    while(path != 2):
        if(path==0):
            if(not(taken[path])):
                taken[path] = True
                days += 2.0

        if(path==1):
            if(not(taken[path])):
                taken[path] = True
                days += 3.0

        path = choose_path()
    days += 1.0
   # print("Days = {}".format(days))

print("Average for {} iterations = {}".format(N, days/N))
```

***In contrast to the some of the other codes my guy doesn't take the same route twice.*** I'm not sure how you problem is defined. My solution seems to be 3.5.
Some of the mistakes you made are:

- `=+` is an assignment of a positive number `a = +3` or `a = -3`
  `+=` is an increment `a = a + 3 <=> a += 3`
- you define door, but never use it
- you never define steps but you use it

I think you should come up with an algorithm first and then implement it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code. For example, you define a `door` list of possible choices, but then you pass `path` to the `choice` function. At the end of your program you print `steps`, but that's not defined anywhere. Instead, you should be printing `days`, or `days / 1000`. You need to pay attention to things like that when you're programming!

As others have shown,  you need to do this with two loops. Each iteration of the outer loop performs a trial. The inner loop chooses paths until you get home and adds the day counts to the current total.

In your code, each `if` test generates a fresh random choice on top of the one you make at the start of the loop. That's not right. Just make the choice at the top of the loop, determine how many days to add to the count, and if you're home, break out of the loop.

We can do this in a simpler way. Rather than choosing from 'a', 'b', or 'c', just choose from 1, 2, or 3, the number of days each path takes. And as I said earlier, there's no need to use Numpy for this, we can just call the `random` module functions directly instead of letting Numpy do it on our behalf.

Here's a short demo.

```
from random import randint

trials = 10000
days = 0
for n in range(trials):
    while True:
        path = randint(1, 3)
        days += path
        if path == 1:
            break

print(days, days / trials)
```

**typical output**

```
59996 5.9996
```

---

We can get a more accurate estimate to the true expected time by performing multiple runs and averaging the results. We could do that by wrapping the previous code in an extra loop, but it makes the code more readable if instead we wrap the old code in a function, and call that function in a loop. Like this:

```
from random import randint

def sim(trials):
    days = 0
    for n in range(trials):
        while True:
            path = randint(1, 3)
            days += path
            if path == 1:
                break
    return days

num = 10
trials = 10000
total = 0
for i in range(num):
    days = sim(trials)
    x = days / trials
    print(i, x)
    total += x

print('Final', total / num)
```

**typical output**

```
0 5.9732
1 6.007
2 6.0555
3 5.9943
4 5.9964
5 5.9514
6 6.0689
7 6.0457
8 5.9859
9 5.9685
Final 6.00468
```

---

It looks like the true expected value is 6 days. Actually, it's not hard to show that mathematically.

Let d equal the expected number of days to get home. 1/3 of the time we get home in 1 day, 1/3 of the time we get back to the start in 2 days and so we still have d days before we get home, and 1/3 of the time we get back to the start in 3 days and so, once again we still have d days before we get home.

We can put that into an equation:

```
d = (1/3)*1 + (1/3)*(2 + d) + (1/3)*(3 + d)
3*d = 1 + 2 + d + 3 + d
3*d = 6 + 2*d
d = 6
```